# how to hide only application logo from action bar programmatically?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to hide the logo from the action bar using the code. i want the other things to remain on actionbar. Can anyone let me know how to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First way:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Second way:

```
getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```